# Why I can not get the `name` - key of the product directly and I have to use a for_in loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I have a `toggleFavorites` `Redux action` in my app, and I save the `favorites id` on a `Firebase database`. When I `fetch` the `favorites` from the server I try to get the `name` - key of each `id` in order to run a second fetch and `DELETE` it. 
What I do not understand is why I need to use a `for_in` loop to get the `name` - key of the `favorite`?

Namely when I `POST` a `favorite` I can access it WITH OUT a `for_in` loop.

Here is the `outputs` of the `logs` (they are also in the code as comments):

`console.log('POST: resData.name', resData.name);
Output: POST: resData.name: -Lr8FPwl5V5PYRlnJ7uh`

`console.log('fetch: resData.name', resData.name);
Output: fetch: resData.name: **undefined**`

`console.log('key:', key);
Output: key: -Lr8FPwl5V5PYRlnJ7uh`

After some comments I found out that if I log

`console.log('JSON.stringify(resData))`

where I get `resData.name : undefined`
I get:

`Output: 
{"-Lr8N_5Zu75y46aHw5FV":{"id":"-LqzSctzym_uQ6CYd7Hw","isFav":true}}`

So there is no `name` property in `fetch`, `DELETE`, `PATCH`.

But if I log the same code in `POST` then I get

`{"name":"-Lr8Nv-EI5KeqTFnerYo"}`

So only the `response` from `POST` has a `name` property.

Here is the code (check the notes):

```
export const toggleFavorite = (id, isFav) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try { 
// If it is a favorite, post it.
            if (isFav) {
                const response = await fetch('https://app.firebaseio.com/favorites.json', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        id,
                        isFav
                    }) 

                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(
                        'Something went wrong.'
                    );
                }
                const resData = await response.json();

                console.log('POST: resData.name', resData.name); // This is NOT undefined?
//Output: POST: resData.name -Lr8FPwl5V5PYRlnJ7uh

console.log('POST JSON.stringify(resData)', JSON.stringify(resData))
// Output: POST JSON.stringify(resData) {"name":"-Lr8Nv-EI5KeqTFnerYo"}

                dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_FAVORITE, productId: id });
            } else if (!isFav) {

                // First get the key in order to delete it in second fetch(...).
                const response = await fetch(`https://app.firebaseio.com/favorites/.json`);

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(
                        'Something went wrong.'
                    );
                }

                const resData = await response.json();

                console.log('fetch: resData.name', resData.name); // Why is this undefined?
// Output: fetch: resData.name undefined

console.log('JSON.stringify(resData)', JSON.stringify(resData)) 
// Output: JSON.stringify(resData) {"-Lr8Nv-EI5KeqTFnerYo":{"id":"-LqzSctzym_uQ6CYd7Hw","isFav":true}

                for (const key in resData) {
                    console.log(key); // OK! Output: key: -Lr8FPwl5V5PYRlnJ7uh
                    await fetch(`https://ekthesi-7767c.firebaseio.com/favorites/${key}.json`, {
                        method: 'DELETE'
                    });

                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(
                            'Something went wrong.'
                            );
                        }

                        dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_FAVORITE, productId: id });
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                // send to custom analytics server
                throw err;
            }
        };
    };
```

Actually I've tried to get the `name` also in `PATCH` but again I get `undefined`.
It works well only with `POST`. 
Can anyone please explain?

Comment: `favorites/.json`  wrong URL? Also, in `for (const key in resData)`, what does `console.log(key)` show? Does it show `name`?

Comment: Hello @Phil. 1. Thanks for noting the typo... It seams though that this was not really a problem, since it still shows `undefined`. 2. Yes `console.log(key)` shows the name! I can get it in the `for_in` loop. That's why I can then delete it! The problem is outside the `for_in` loop. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Phil I edited the code above. Now you can see the outputs plus the output of `resData` alone, which BTW log **nothing**. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the overlook. Here is the output: ``{"-Lr8M5lmDKN_HqK2-_Bo":{"id":"-LqzSctzym_uQ6CYd7Hw","isFav":true}}``

Comment: Right, so it has no `name` property, that is why `resData.name` is `undefined`. Do you have the value `"-Lr8M5lmDKN_HqK2-_Bo"` stored in a variable anywhere?

Comment: Yes you're right... But, this property gets generated from Firebase when I add a favorite. I don't have the value. That's why I try to get it from Firebase when I do `fetch...` BTW Here is what I get if I do the same (`console.log('resData', JSON.stringify(resData))`)when I `POST` a favorite: ```Output: {"name":"-Lr8Nv-EI5KeqTFnerYo"}``` So in POST there is a `name` prop but nowhere else!